# C#, showing a variable on screen

Tags: c#, variables, xna

The game that i am making using C# is Square Chase. You mouse over the block and click it before it moves. The timer will count down in the back ground and the score will be raised by 1 each "tag" on the block. You can do the Project on XNA 4.0 Game Development by Example. This is 2010 C# and The project type is Windows Game (4.0).

Now I want to add extra stuff to it. I want take away 5 seconds of time every time they click on the block, but I don't know if its working so I need to make the time remaining visible. I want to make it smaller every time you hit the square.

Code: (under update and the if statement I have already done the subtraction on the time but would want to make sure its working by making it visible) Thank You

**I need to find out how to sink and in large an image, I need to know how to show a float on the screen.**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Audio;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GamerServices;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media;

namespace RFSquareChase
{
    /// <summary>
    /// This is the main type for your game
    /// </summary>
    public class Game1 : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game
    {
        GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
        SpriteBatch spriteBatch;

        Random rand = new Random ();
        Texture2D squareTexture;
        Rectangle currentSquare;
        int playerScore = 0;
        float timeRemaining = 0.0f;
        const float TimePerSquare = 0.75f;
        Color [] colors = new Color[3] { Color.Red, Color.Green, Color.Blue };

        public Game1()
        {
            graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
            Content.RootDirectory = "Content";
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Allows the game to perform any initialization it needs to before starting to run.
        /// This is where it can query for any required services and load any non-graphic
        /// related content.  Calling base.Initialize will enumerate through any components
        /// and initialize them as well.
        /// </summary>
        protected override void Initialize()
        {
            // TODO: Add your initialization logic here

            base.Initialize();

            this.IsMouseVisible = true;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// LoadContent will be called once per game and is the place to load
        /// all of your content.
        /// </summary>
        protected override void LoadContent()
        {
            // Create a new SpriteBatch, which can be used to draw textures.
            spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);

            squareTexture = Content.Load<Texture2D>(@"SQUARE");

            // TODO: use this.Content to load your game content here
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// UnloadContent will be called once per game and is the place to unload
        /// all content.
        /// </summary>
        protected override void UnloadContent()
        {
            // TODO: Unload any non ContentManager content here
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Allows the game to run logic such as updating the world,
        /// checking for collisions, gathering input, and playing audio.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="gameTime">Provides a snapshot of timing values.</param>
        protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            // Allows the game to exit
            if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).Buttons.Back == ButtonState.Pressed)
                this.Exit();

            // TODO: Add your update logic here

            if (timeRemaining == 0.0f)
            {
                currentSquare = new Rectangle(
                    rand.Next(0, this.Window.ClientBounds.Width - 25),
                    rand.Next(0, this.Window.ClientBounds.Height - 25),
                    25, 25);
                timeRemaining = TimePerSquare;
            }

            MouseState mouse = Mouse.GetState();

            if ((mouse.LeftButton == ButtonState.Pressed) && 
                (currentSquare.Contains(mouse.X, mouse.Y)))
            {
                playerScore++;
                timeRemaining = 0.0f;
                timeRemaining = timeRemaining - 5;
            }
            timeRemaining = MathHelper.Max(0, timeRemaining - (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds);

            this.Window.Title = "Score : " + playerScore.ToString();

            base.Update(gameTime);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// This is called when the game should draw itself.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="gameTime">Provides a snapshot of timing values.</param>
        protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.Gray);

            spriteBatch.Begin();
            spriteBatch.Draw(
                squareTexture,
                currentSquare,
                colors[playerScore % 3]);
            spriteBatch.End();

            // TODO: Add your drawing code here

            base.Draw(gameTime);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: why can't you just have a label on the form show the time remaining at each `Update(\*...*\)`?

Comment: Look into Spritebatch.DrawString

Comment: @iabbott: XNA projects don't have form controls.

Comment: I have been able to see that timeRemaining is affected by TimePerSquare, I need to so how turn my score to a decimal. I should be able to do that but I still do not how to show the time on screen I had to do: this.Window.Title = "Time : " + timeRemaining.ToString();

Comment: So what is your question? You want us to do it for you (which is why, I assume, you posted your entire code base, relevant code or not)?

Comment: I need to find out how to sink and in large an image, I need to know how to show a float on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

To show a float on screen you simply use `spriteBatch.DrawString`, and could be useful `Math.Round` to show only the decimal you want. As you can see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphics.spritebatch.drawstring.aspx).

To change the dimension of a sprite you can set the `scale` parameter in your `spriteBatch.Draw`. As you can see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphics.spritebatch.draw.aspx)